# Is it secure to use RequestUri an IIS request arrives to selectively turn off authentication/authorization?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net Web API RESTful service, that has an OAuth2 style token based security for for authorization. This service would run on premise for each client of my software.

They wish to have outside (i.e. outside their firewall) access to it, where we would use the token based security, but also want to connect to it via some other applications that run behind their firewall (other non windows services), and since these applications, and the endpoint used in the IIS binding are only available behind their firewall, skip using any of the authentication/authorization.

I though perhaps one way of allowing this is to examine which RequestUri a request arrives on, and if this is the endpoint is the one setup for "internal" behind the firewall access, I could then allow the request to go though without checking for the security token, i.e. just return true in my instance of `ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess`

Does this seem safe? Is there anyway someone from outside of the firewall trick the request to thinking into came in via this "unsecured" endpoint?

Thanks in advance for any information.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be **no**.

I can edit my local host file and enter whatever I want. Eg if I enter...

```
127.0.0.1 timmy.peepcee.com
```

The I can send a request via `timmy.peepcee.com`, IIS allows it in, and this is the RequestUri I get...

[image]

There really seems to be no way of having more than one authentication scheme.